# Shopping cart ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, addition

Shopping cart with ArrayList of desk to purchase indicating the quantity which should not be more than quantity in stock. I tried this one:

```
public void addToPurchaseCart(desk furniture,int quantity)
    {
        if (purchased.quantityInStock>quantity){
            purchased.add(furniture);
        }
    }
```

It doesn`t work!

Comment: What language are you using and what is the value of `quantity` and `quantityInStock`?

Comment: BlueJ; the quantity is to enter and the quantity in stock is in another class (need to call)

Comment: But you said it's not working, and the code seems alright. So what are the values of quantity and quantityInStock? How do you know it's not working? Maybe there is actually less quantityInStock than you think. Please post more code (the quantityInStock class)